# Android update on Google Play - want to delete old data

Tags: android, resources, google-play, updates, delete-file

I'm going to release new update of my app on Google play store. I use some resources stored on user's SD card (\sdcard\Android\package\data...). I make some important updates and want to replace these old files. Is there any way to delete all these files before updating? (Some flag "delete old version's files" on GPlay) Like uninstall and reinstall of the app. I can do it my way in app (try to delete old files if present). But this approach (via some installation routine) is smart, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it by yourself, because Google Play Store wouldn't do it for you.